# SQL _Click data for part of a URL string

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql

I'm trying to query the last 6 months of clicks for a URL in SFMC. Because we add UTMs and parameter strings to the base URL, it changes in each email. I'm not having much luck using 'LIKE' but I am returning a few records. Here is the query example:

```
SELECT
SubscriberKey,
JobID as JobID,
URL,
EventDate
FROM ent._Click  
Where 
URL LIKE 'https://www.mybaseurl/en/gift-cards%'
AND EventDate > convert(date, getDate()-180)
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Your query is fine, although are you running the query in the Child Business Unit you want to check or are you consciously trying to check the Enterprise BU? You could maybe try removing the ENT. and/or using the LinkContent field rather than the URL field on the off chance your link (or any part of it) is stored in an AMPscript variable.
Worth noting your EventDate filter is redundant too...the data view only contains 6 months of data anyway.

Comment: Great suggestions, thank you! I was consciously checking the enterprise BU but actually made no difference. I replaced 'URL LIKE' with 'LinkContent LIKE' and that made no difference but a good suggestion I hadn't considered.